# Blackberry - Device SDK Version Information

Tags: blackberry, sdk

How do I find out the sdk version of my blackberry ?

I have a Blackberry 8520 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Options - About` on your device.

Operating system version is equal to the SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

blackberry 8520 uses OS5 and cant be upgraded *officially* to OS6 or OS7. So SDK for 8520 will be [v5.0](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javasdk5.jsp)